# Apply formula in an Excel comment

Tags: excel, vba, comments, formula, cells

I would like to make a comment a dynamic cell. For example, if I change a value in a cell, the comment should change. I've tried:

```
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
file = Application.GetOpenFilename
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(file)
ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For J = 1 To ws2
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(J).Activate
    For x2 = 18 To 245
        For y2 = 1 To 23
        Worksheets(J).Select
        wb2.Activate
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Cells(x2, y2).Select
        Selection.ClearNotes
        Selection.NoteText Text:=wb.Worksheets(J).Cells(x2, y2).Value
        Next y2
    Next x2
Next J
```

and the code works to copy cells but not to copy dynamically. If I change `A` to `B` I want a `B` in the comment.

This code works if i change the same line :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      '//clearing more than one cell causes an error
      On Error Resume Next
      '//(can't overwrite an existing comment)
      Target.ClearComments
      ActiveCell.Select
      With Selection
            'get the previous value when value changes
            .AddComment
            .Comment.Visible = False
            .Comment.Text Text:="" & Target
      End With
End Sub
```

The result, if you validate (no enter else the comment is in the next line) you have the comment like the cell. Now i need this in the same case in the other file.

Thanks

Comment: Yes for example.
I try this :
Selection.NoteText Text:=ActiveCell.Value
but it does not change in function

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question without some examples. Chances are you can build this with just Excel formula, no VBA required. Anyhow, examples please?

Comment: Ok,
A is the value of the cell.
If I change this value to B. It also mut change to B in the comment.

Comment: Aparemment la solution viendrait de la fonction Target comme ceci :
ByVal Target As Range
Mais je ne sais pas m'en servir

Answer (score 0):

Here, the final code for whose who are interrested.

```
   Option Explicit
Dim newRange As Range
Public wbx As Workbook
Dim x, y As Integer
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error Resume Next

x = ActiveCell.row
y = ActiveCell.Column

Workbooks("Test2.xlsb").Activate

Target.ClearComments

'Sheets(2).Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(x - 2, y - 1).Select

    With Selection
        .AddComment
        .Comment.Visible = False
        .Comment.Text Text:="" & Target
    End With

Workbooks("Test1.xlsb").Activate


End Sub
```